# Rails ActiveStorage File not found in sidekiq task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq, rails-activestorage

I have image in my project with `ActiveStorage.attach`

```
if params[:avatar]
  authorize! :update, current_user
  type, base64_image = Utils::Attach.type_and_base64(params[:avatar], 'avatar')
  current_user.avatar.attach(io: StringIO.new(base64_image), filename: "#{current_user.id}-#{Time.current.to_i}", content_type: type)
  current_user.save!
end
```

And it actually work good.
But after I add sidekiq for mailer I started saw error[image: sidekiqscreenshot]

This error adds after attach avatar.
[image: ActiveStorage::Blob]

Comment: There is not any information about *sidekiq for mailer* in your question

Comment: mechnicov, i don't have problem with mailer I only see error with activestorage

Comment: May be somewhere you call `attachment.purge_later` or similar method but there is no such files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't found correct way to fix analyze job but monkey patching is work good for my case.

```
  module ActiveStorage::Blob::Analyzable
    def analyze_later
      analyze
    end
  end
```